# Showing a label for a minimum amount of time breaks when called quickly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm showing a notification label when a button is clicked and it works fine but if I press the button more than once sometimes the notification goes away immediately.

```js
var duration = 3000;

function showNotificationLabel() {
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

    messageLabel.textContent = "Task Complete at " + time;

    setTimeout(() => {
      messageLabel.textContent = "";
    }, duration);
  }
```

```css
body {
  font: caption;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="messageLabel"></span>&nbsp;
</p>

<div>
  <button onclick="showNotificationLabel()">Start</button>
</div>
```

How do I ensure the label doesn't disappear before the timeout occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time you click, a new independent timeout is initiated with the same callback function.

To prevent this, you should clear the previous timeout on each click:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

```js
var duration = 3000;
var timeOutRef = null;

function showNotificationLabel() {
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();

    messageLabel.textContent = "Task Complete at " + time;

    if(timeOutRef != null) clearTimeout(timeOutRef);

    timeOutRef = setTimeout(() => {
      messageLabel.textContent = "";
    }, duration);
  }
```

```css
body {
  font: caption;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="messageLabel"></span>&nbsp;
</p>

<div>
  <button onclick="showNotificationLabel()">Start</button>
</div>
```